# How to check if jPanel is pressed?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have JPanel called `panelCrtanje`.
I need to change cBox state if it is pressed.

```
final PadDraw drawPad = new PadDraw();
panelCrtanje.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
panelCrtanje.add(drawPad, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

It works before I add drawPad to panelCrtanje using this:

```
private void panelCrtanjeMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
 slikaC.setSelected(true);
}
```

PadDraw looks like this

```
public PadDraw(){
    setDoubleBuffered(false);
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            oldX = e.getX();
            oldY = e.getY();
        }
    });

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter()){
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
            currentX = e.getX();
            currentY = e.getY();
            if(graphics2D != null) {
             graphics2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(18F,BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
            graphics2D.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);
            repaint();
            oldX = currentX;
            oldY = currentY;
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: How to check if jPanel is pressed? == from code posted here isn't possible, but there are two choices 1. read Oracle tutorial about MouseListener, 2. for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use MouseEvent properly. To use it the class needs to implement MouseListener. Then you need to create a listener for the mouse event like so:

```
panelCrtanje.addMouseListener();
```

Then use these methods that are required in MouseListener and MotionMouseListener

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO In HERE do what you want to do

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

When the mouse is clicked: mouseClicked
When the mouse is held down but not moved: mousePressed
When the mouse is released: mouseReleased
When the mouse enters the window: mouseEntered
When the mouse leaves the window: mouseExited

That is how you can use the mouseListener to do different things.

Answer (score 0):

you should register a `MouseListener` on `panelCartanje`, I have used an anonymous inner class to do this.

```
    panelCrtanje.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            /// cBox state change goes here . . .
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution

```
    MouseAdapter adap = new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        slikaC.setSelected(true);
    }
    };
```